# ideal diode resitance

Tags: diodes

the questions goes like this: model ideal diode (0.75V battery and 100 Ohms resistance)  and then calculate the average V0.
I know how to add the 0.75V but how can I add the resistance to the diode? just in series I suppose?

[image]

Comment: Yes - but also keep in mind that this model only works for Vi greater than .75 volts.

Comment: An ideal diode has no forward voltage drop and no series resistance (that's what makes it "ideal"). A real diode can be approximated by putting a voltage source and a resistance in series with an ideal diode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you aren't modelling an ideal diode, you're modelling a physical diode to first order.  An ideal diode has zero 'on' resistance and infinite 'off' resistance.

Your model should look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3rHab.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>